# What does it mean to say someone is "of" somewhere?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, prepositions

For example:

> William Howell of Fishguard, Pembrokeshire, sang Our Gallant Ship..

Does it mean the place where the person was born? Or could it also just mean the place where they lived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take it to mean the place where they live, not necessarily that they were born there.

Comment: Yes.  I think it effectively refers to their **address**.